# Manage update_cart and empty_cart in expresso store using transcribe

Tags: expresso-store, transcribe

I'm using Transcribe v1.6.1 and Expresso Store v2.4.1 (EE v 2.9.2)
I'm using the empty_cart and update_cart inputs in one of my templates.  These work fine for the default English language but when translated they cause the page to redirect to the English language version.  I noticed that even though I have set my next parameter in {exp:store:checkout} on looking at the html output there is an input named RET which has the English url in it.

```
<input type="hidden" value="de/zur-kasse-gehen" name="return_url">
<input type="hidden" value="de/zur-kasse-gehen" name="next_url">
<input type="hidden" value="23" name="ACT">
<input type="hidden" value="checkout/basket" name="RET">
<input type="hidden" value="6" name="site_id">
<input type="hidden" value="2b4ace44ef575d89250020c6306c639ed284ae98" name="csrf_token">
<input type="hidden" value="CyYLdVppBWNaeQduVw4LbwhiCjAEdlooUiFTPQAqBGUBbFx3BD8BIwM9Xm0GIVMzUXoOZQNrC3hTNA45VXYKJ1UmATsJZAZ5BXMJclQ4XHELOQsyWlMFI1pxB3ZXIwshCGUKMAR2WihSZlMqAG8EZgFrXGAEPAEsA3leIAYhUz9RdA5/A3cLYlN3Dm9VdgpvVWEBCQkuBnsFcgkiVC9cOAs8CyRafAVpWiYHZFc0C2QIawo/BCdad1IhU3QAbQRgAXZcdwQ3AVEDNF5hBidTM1FvDmQDJws2U3cOLFUxCnhVJgF5CSMGcgViCTNUd1whCzgLCFp9BWlafwd2VyMLYggsCmsEJ1oiUmZTdAAqBC8BIVxgBDwBbQMnXnsGI1MuUWUObgNaC3xTNA4nVTUKZlV3AXcJOwYwBXo=" name="_params">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="secure_return">
```

Does anyone know how to get this to play nicely with Transcribe?

Comment: Can you show us your {exp:store:checkout} parameters?

Answer (score 0):

The folks at DevDemon have sent me an updated version of the script and now the update_cart function works correctly.  I've asked if they could also fix the empty_cart function.